# "Kick off tracking time in the notepad" means start making notes or stop making notes

Tags: meaning, phrases, meaning-in-context, synonyms

I'm not sure for 100% if "Kick off tracking time in the notepad" means to start or, otherwise, to stop tracking time in the notepad.

Could anybody explain?
Thank you.

Comment: "Kick off" normally means to start something - in particular, it's the first action in a football (soccer) match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*kick off*

> 2. *Informal*: To begin; start: kicked off the promotional tour with a press conference.

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/kick+off)

> to take the first step in (a process or course of action)

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kick%20off)